# First order theories, interpretation, concrete example, proof

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

I read a proof that no model of a certain f.o. theory $T_1$ is definable in $(Q,<)$ and I have a problem with understanding the very end of Lemma 3.2 [here.](https://www.coursehero.com/file/pvom2/Let-T-1-be-the-theory-of-strict-linear-orderings-where-every-element-has-an/)

"The distance from $\alpha_i$ to $\alpha_k$ is $k-i$.
This is a contradiction"

My question is:***A contradiction with what?***

The answer will be short,and the setting is on a single page in the link above,so I should not restate it here.

Comment: Linking to something is only useful if other people can see the link. Google tells this page is unavalable for viewing.

Comment: Is this any better? [Lemma 3.2](https://www.coursehero.com/file/pvom2/Let-T-1-be-the-theory-of-strict-linear-orderings-where-every-element-has-an/)

Comment: It seems that Lemma 3.2 asserts that no discrete linear order is interpretable in $(\mathbb{Q},<)$. If you've learned about countably categorical theories, there's an easier way to state the argument: The theory of $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is countably categorical, and countable categoricity is preserved under interpretation, but no discrete linear order has a countably categorical theory, because there are infinitely many non-equivalent formulas in $2$ free variables (for example, asserting that the distance between $x$ and $y$ is $n$, for each $n$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\alpha_i, \alpha_j)$ is carried to $(\alpha_i, \alpha_k)$, where $i < j < k$. Apparently (I'd have to see more of the development to be sure), this mapping should preserve distance. But the first distance is $j - i$, while the second is $k - i$.

Comment: I think that you gave me a good clue.